# How to concatenate 2 4-dimensional array in R programming by last dimension

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have created 2 4-dimensional array in R (let's say 3 rows, 3 columns, 2 visits, 1 year). My code looks something like this:

```
a1=  c (1,2,3,4)
a2= c (5,6,7,8,9)
r.names = c ("c1","c2","c3")
c.names = c ("r1","r2","r3")
v.names = c("v1","v2")
m.names = c ("first")

arr = array (c (a1,a2), dim=c (3,3,2,1), dimnames=list (c.names, r.names, v.names, m.names))
print(arr)

b1=  c (1,2,3,4)
b2= c (5,6,7,8,9)
r.names = c ("c1","c2","c3")
c.names = c ("r1","r2","r3")
v.names = c("v1","v2")
m.names = c ("second")

arr2 = array (c (a1,a2), dim=c (3,3,2,1), dimnames=list (c.names, r.names, v.names, m.names))
print(arr2)
```

Now I want to concatenate arr2 after arr but also increase the last dimension from 1 to 2. I am doing this so that for 1 year I have 3 rows 3 columns 2 visits and then for second year I have 3 rows 3 columns and 2 visits.

I hope this makes sense

So ultimately I want this:
[image]

Any help suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Le

I tried abind. I think I am just stuck

Comment: I got it, and it was a stupid typo!